# Null pointer while looping though firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I may be missing something, can some one help me point it out, i am trying to loop this this node in firebase then get the child 'idno' but when i toast the full snapshot  ie (snapshot.getValue().toString()), it returns the complete data set, however trying to get the child from the snapshot as such gives a null pointer snapshot.child("idno").getValue().toString(), please help me figure out what am missing

[image: The Node]

```
DatabaseReference thefarmers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Thepath").child("Farmers");
thefarmers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //Get the child id
            theMethods.makeLongToast(snapshot.child("idno").getValue().toString());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

This  theMethods.makeLongToast(); is a simple method that takes a string and makes a Toast

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: It looks like one of the child nodes doesn't have an `idno` property. You might want to print `Log.i("TAG", dataSnapshot.getKey())` first inside the loop, to see which child is causing the problem.

Comment: My bad @ Frank van Puffelen, got it.

Comment: Thanks @ Frank van Puffelen, turns out the first sub - child's  idno property is 'idno"' instead of 'idno'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change This line

```
theMethods.makeLongToast(snapshot.child("idno").getValue().toString());
```

to

```
if (snapshot.hasChild("idno") && snapshot.child("idno") != null)
    theMethods.makeLongToast(snapshot.child("idno").getValue(String.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `thefarmers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()`

with `thefarmers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()`

Comment: both of them return the same Reference,the only difference is first line get value for one and the second listent everytime it change!

Answer (score 0):

From @ Frank van Puffelen's comment, turns out the first sub - child's idno property is 'idno"' instead of 'idno', this fixed it for me.